# heroku how to add $PATH inside heroku app

Tags: heroku

On my App folder, there is a bin folder, and I want it to add it in the $PATH like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

I tried it in heroku bash but then heroku will restart and remove the added Path. How will I able to add this to the $path permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the heroku CLI tool, config?

`heroku config:set PATH=~/bin`

This seems a little odd though. It seems there might be a better way to accomplish what you're trying to achieve. But I don't really know anything about your stack so it's hard to comment.

Regardless, if you want environment variables to stick in Heroku, set them with `heroku config` or use the management console: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOURAPPNAME/settings

Heroku config docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I already tried that "heroku config:set PATH=~/bin" and the dashboard and the app is crashing. When I try to heroku run bash it says Error: No such file or directory
Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
When i remove that config its fine. I am using multiple buildpacks in an app and my stack is cedar 14.

Comment: Update: I check the config on dashboard settings and its pointing to the local folder. I need to point it in the deployed folder

Comment: What type of app is it? Node? Ruby? ??